# List (or move) only files with a certain number of lines?

Tags: files, grep, find, mv, wc

Dealing with a whole bunch of two-line config files, I'd like a way to exclude any files that have a different number of lines.

So, something like:

```
mv * destdir only if file contains exactly two lines
```

Or:

```
wc -l * | grep '^ *2' | xargs mv {} destdir
```

Except that neither of those is actual working code.

While writing this I realized I *do* have a way to do this, which is ugly as heck, and I've included it below as an answer.

Is there an easy/clean way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your kludgy solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245567/44356) isn't too bad for starters... you are just missing the fact that not only can `awk` give you the number of lines, you can also instruct it to [exit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) with the right status code so that you can then chain it with the `cp` command:

```
for file in * ; do awk 'NR==3{exit}END{exit NR!=2}' "$file" && cp "$file" /tmp; done
```

[`NR` is the number of records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-NR-variable-1), and as suggested in [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245575/44356)'s answer, we can use the `NR==3` check to stop further processing once we encounter a third line.

`NR!=2` looks funny, because `awk`'s `true/false` values are `1/0`, but in the shell, we need `0` to represent a success status for `&&` to work correctly. The inverse of that works too (depending on how strongly do you react to seeing `!=`):

```
for file in * ; do awk 'NR==3{exit}END{exit NR==2}' "$file" || cp "$file" /tmp; done
```

Comment: I like this solution because (a) it doesn't assume the filenames are sane (b) it is POSIX compatible.  (Also it doesn't depend on zsh, which I know nothing about.)

Comment: I made use of Awk as a `wc` substitute [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327402/135943), also.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `awk`, `exit` on line `3` (the `END` rule is still executed) and `exit 1` in the `END` block if no. of lines is not `2` e.g. with `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- *(.e_'awk "NR==3{exit}END{if(NR!=2){exit 1}}" $REPLY'_)
```

will list two-line files in the current directory; replace `print -rl` with `mv` and add the destination if you want to move them.
With other shells:

```
for file in ./*; do [[ -f $file ]] && \
awk 'NR==3{exit};END{if(NR!=2){exit 1}}' "$file" && mv "$file" "$dest"
done
```

---

Other ways, e.g. with `z` shell
and *gnu* `awk`:

```
awk 'ENDFILE{if(FNR==2){print FILENAME}}' ./*(.)
```

or *gnu* `sed` (v. `4.2.2` or later):

```
sed -ns '2{$F}' ./*(.)
```

to list the two-line files<sup>1</sup> and e.g.:

```
for f (./*(.))
sed -n '2{$Q 1};3q' $f || mv $f $dest
```

to move them.

---

<sup>1: those would both go through the whole input so not really suited if you're working with huge files; in that case, you may want to `sed -n '2{$F};3q'` for each file or use the first awk solution</sup>

Comment: What does `F` do in `sed`?  I can't find documentation on it anywhere.  Or is that a typo?

Comment: Using GNU sed 4.2.1, `sed F filename` returns `unknown command: 'F'`.  And looking through the entirety of `info sed` I don't see it mentioned anywhere.  Did you test it?  What version of `sed` are you using?  EDIT: Ah, I see the link in your comment now.  I suspected that's what it was supposed to do...but it doesn't work on my CentOS 6 vagrant box.

Comment: @Wildcard - yes, my bad for not specifying that `F` was added in [`sed 4.2.2`](https://lwn.net/Articles/530460/)

Answer (score 2):

if your filenames are fairly sane, and you can delimit on both `:` and a newline, then:

```sh
grep -m3 '' ./* ./*/* |
cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c |
grep -v '^ *[13] '
```

^that command will list all not-dot files in the current directory and in all immediate child directories which contain only two lines.

You don't really need to worry about sorting for `uniq`, because globs are sorted. I use the GNU `-m`ax match option because it is much faster if `grep` quits at the third input line than it is if it continues through to the end, but it will work without it as well. The idea is to get `grep` to print the filenames for each line they contain, then to count the occurences of each filename in its output, and then to filter out anything more or less than 2.

I ran it against some random source code dirs, and, of all of them, I had two files which contained only the two lines:

```
  2 ./dex/coll.sh
  2 ./jimtcl/jim-config.h.in
```

it would be neater to replace the last line with:

```sh
... |
sed -ne's/^ *2  *//p'
```

...though.

Comment: Assuming sane filenames in any context is something I dislike.  But yes, if you're comfortable assuming that (and you're doing it interactively, not scripting it), then this is good.

Comment: @Wildcard - if you're not comfortable with it, you can do `find . ! -type d ! -path "*[:$IFS]*" -exec ... {} +` and then invert the selection with a more conservative approach for a second run. Just make sure `$IFS` is set to a default value first, or drop the space and tab if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the following kludgy solution:

```
for file in * ; do if [ "$(wc -l "$file" | awk '{print $1}')" == "2" ] ; then cp "$file" /tmp/ ; fi; done
```

There must be a better way which doesn't start two processes for every single file in the current directory.

Comment: If process count is a concern, you can save a process by doing `if [ -r "$file" ] && [ $(wc -l < "$file") -eq 2 ]`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-t` target directory option on `mv` with `xargs`:

```
wc -l * | sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*2[[:space:]]\+//p'  | xargs mv -t "$DESTDIR"
```

Comment: fwiw, this won't work if the file names contain spaces or other funky chars.