# My first Shell that count rows in each file

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to run a shell script that counts the number of rows in each file,
and if the number < 2 I need to move it to a different directory.

shell:

```
#!/bin/bash


foreach i in (ls *.DAT)
  a=`wc -l $i`
  if $a=<2 then
    mv $i aux1/pelvar/var/pel/projs/ar/shells/IGUD_OUT/backup      
  endif
end
```

But my shell gets an error:

> igud_to_backup.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
> igud_to_backup.sh: line 8: `foreach i in (ls *.DAT)'

What is wrong with the shell script?

Comment: see also [List (or move) only files with a certain number of lines?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245566)

Comment: Is that a `csh` or `tcsh` shell script? (I'm unfamiliar with them but) If it is, the `#!`-line is wrong and should point to the `csh` executable instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems:

- `foreach` is not a bash keyword: use `for`
- if you want to execute a command use `$( ... )` and not just the parenthesis
- the command execution in the parenthesis is not needed you can just use shell expansion `for i in *.DAT; do` (in general see [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls))
- to test if a value is less or equal (see `man test`): `if [ $a -le 2 ] ; then`
- a `for` is ended by `done` and not `end`
- an `if` is ended by `fi` and not `endif`
- if you give the file name as an argument to `wc` it will print the number of lines **and** the file name. Use `<` to make `wc` read from standard input

To sum up:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *DAT; do
  a=$( wc -l < "$i" )
  if [ "$a" -le 2 ] ; then
    mv "$i" aux1/pelvar/var/pel/projs/ar/shells/IGUD_OUT/backup
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hey,
thanks a lot, now it is much better. but still getting error: unknown operator

Comment: @don_crissti Oops sorry

Comment: @Elislu What do you mean?

Comment: Hey,
The Shell:

#!/bin/sh
for i in $(ls *.DAT); do
  if [ "$a" -ge 2 ] ; then
    mv ${i} /aux1/pelvar/var/pel/projs/ar/shells/IGUD_OUT/backup
  fi
done


He should count how many rows there are in each file and then with two or more rows, he should move it to another directory.
But unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: The code you posted in the last comment is not what I suggested. But more importantly you are missing the line assigning the number of rows to a ` a=$( wc -l < "$i" )`

Comment: You're right, now it works!
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As Matteo mentioned you are trying to use perl syntax. Should be;

```
for i in $(ls *.DAT); do
  if [ $(wc -l ${i}) -le 2 ]; then
    mv ${i} /path/to/
  fi
done
```

Comment: Looks more like `csh` syntax to me, but anyway, it isn't `bash`.